# NSInteger crazy value when incrementing

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode6, nsinteger

I've been looking for this problem for quite some time now, so I decided to ask. I seriously don't know what is going on.

I have a tableView and when I select a cell I want it to go to a different view controller. So far all good, the thing is I don't want to keep adding screens, so I was trying to use a counter to check if I already used the normal segue once so I could use the unwind method. With that in mind here is my code snippet

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
NSInteger antcounter;

if (indexPath.row == 0 && indexPath.section == 0 && antcounter < 2) {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ToAntMan" sender:self];
    antcounter ++;
    NSLog(@"%tu", antcounter);
} else if (indexPath.row == 0 && indexPath.section == 0 && antcounter > 2) {
    NSLog(@"%tu", antcounter);
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"unwindToAntMan" sender:self];
    NSLog(@"YES");
```

At the first NSLog I get a value of 2
At the second NSLog I get a crazy value of 1732 and I seriously can't understand. What stupidity am I doing ?

Comment: ?? is 'antcounter' declared at class level or in the function?

Comment: In the function, but it worked the same way when declared class level

Comment: You should define it at class level?

Comment: You don't seem to be understanding unwind segues. If you have a forward segue from A to B, the unwind segue should be initiated from controller B, not controller A. There's no need for this counting business.

Comment: @rdelmar the unwind should be on the destination view, right ? For example, from A to B, if I want to go back to A, the unwind `IBAction` thing would go on the A code, so I could drag on View B to exit to select it. But as you told me the unwind only works if the view already appeared, sometimes it hasn't here in the project, so I need to make it go forward first, before it can actually unwind to it. I hope I made myself clear this time lol

Comment: That's not at all clear to me. I don't know how many different controllers you have, or what controller the above code is in. The only controller that should be calling unwindToAntMan would be a controller that antMan had pushed (or presented) on screen (or one further on). I can't think of a situation where one controller would have to decide whether to go forward to antMan or backwards to it. Lets say you have A->B->AM->D, where A is the initial controller and AM is antMan. B can only go forward to AM, and D should only unwind to AM.  No controller needs to decide which way to go.

Comment: I do see your point @rdelmar. Let me ask you then, the code above is a TableView where it has all the views in the app. So when the user selects the cell it should go to the view selected, which at fist I had to make it go by segue and then go unwinding. Should I just use the segue ? Also when I  select for example D, in your example, and AM hasn't been loaded yet, I can't unwind to AM, because it was never there in first place, because I moved from A to D via the tableView

Comment: I actually changed it all now. I was doing something horrible with a lot of unnecessary code. I'm using `UIPageViewController` now. Thanks for the help @rdelmar and @Shoaib

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NSInteger without initialisation is n't guaranteed to be zero, since it's a local automatic variable and its value is indeterminate. If you want it to be zero.

Either

```
NSUInteger antcounter = 0;
```

Or

```
static NSUInteger antcounter;
```

Apart from this you may declare it Global in header file like below

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger antcounter;
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: you may try then either static NSUInteger antcounter; or make it declare in header as @property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger antcounter; and self.antcounter =0 in didviewload

Comment: The `NSUInteger antcounter = 0;` didn't work here, it just keeps on 0 and 1, every time it kinda gets back to 0. The static didn't work before, but it actually worked now. And I had tried the Global before also, but it gave me the same issue as assigning it a 0 value. Thanks @Santu